# Convert Text-Formatted "Day Name, Month Name, Date of Month, Year" to "YYYY-MM-DD" Date Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with thousands of dates saved in Text format, written the following way:
[image: "Day Name, Month Name, Date of Month, Year" Format]

I want these cells to be converted into "YYYY-MM-DD" format. However, Excel cannot detect these cells as Date Format; hence, when I try to use the "Format Cells" (or Ctrl+1) to change the date format, it does not work and stays the same. I need them to be in "YYYY-MM-DD" because I will be using the date in multiple functions throughout my workbook and the Text formatted Dates do not allow that.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `FILTERXML()` in this way.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

Then format resulting cells as `YYYY-MM-DD`. Or you can use `TEXT()` function to get output directly as date.

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Harun's answer. For if one does not have Windows one could use:
`=TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: Good answer and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

However, you can also use the `Text To Columns` inbuilt feature of Excel From Data Tab to turn those text formatted dates to actual Excel Dates, please follow the steps,

• Select The Range, In Image Below, Its A:A,

[image: RANGE_SELECTED]

• Next From Data Tab, Click Text To Columns

[image: TEXT_TO_COLUMNS]

• In Text To Columns Wizard - Step 1 Of 3 - Click Fixed Width Under Original Data Type and Press Next

[image: STEP_1_OF_3]

• In The Step 2 Of 3 - Move The Lines With Arrow As Shown In The Image Below &
Press Next

Lines With Arrows(Signifies A Column Break)

[image: STEP_2_OF_3]

• The Last & Final Step --> Step 3 Of 3, Under Data Preview, Select The Days Column  And Click -- Do Not Import Column(Skip) From Above Column Data Format & Same Way For The Last Blank Column As Well, Now Click The Date Column And Select From Above Column Data Format as Date (MDY) & Press Finish!

[image: STEP_3_OF_3]

• To Confirm Whether Those Have Been Converted To Actual Excel Date Or Not, You May Use A Formula Like Below Or While Changing The Date Format You Can Select General Or Number Category To Verify

**FORMULA USED TO VERIFY IN CELL B1**

```
=ISNUMBER(A1)
```

[image: DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD]

And You Are Done!